# Joining oracle with mssql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join

When i execute following line i get the result:

```
select * from my_table@link;
```

But when i try to join linked table with other tables like in select i get error that says "z.id - invalid identifier"

```
SELECT

                e.USER_NAME,e.FULL_NAME,r.RFC_NUMBER,r.TYPE, 

                TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.TOTAL_TIME/3600),'FM9900') || ':' ||
                TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD(a.TOTAL_TIME,3600)/60),'FM00') || ':' ||
                TO_CHAR(MOD(a.TOTAL_TIME,60),'FM00') as TOTAL_TIME,

                a.ASSIGN_DATE,a.TIME_START,a.TIME_STOP,
                r.SUBMITTED_BY,r.REGISTER_DATE,r.DESCRIPTION 


                FROM table_a a 
                JOIN table_r ON a.REQ_ID = r.REQ_ID 
                JOIN table_e e ON e.emp_id = a.emp_id

                LEFT JOIN my_table@link z ON e.emp_id = z.id

                WHERE a.ASSIGN_DATE > '01-JAN-2013' and a.ASSIGN_DATE < '01-JAN-2015'

                ORDER BY r.RFC_NUMBER;
```

table_a, table_r and table_e are oracle tables.
table my_table is mssql table that is being accessed via link.

so my question is how to join oracle tables with linked mssql table?

Comment: What is the result you get from executing the first query? Is there a column named `id`?

Comment: yes, i get all the data that are in that table. everything is ok with column names and aliases i've checked multiple times.

Comment: Is the column `id` in lowercase? If you don't put quotes around a column name in Oracle, it assumes uppercase. So `z.id` will look for a column named `ID` while `z."id"` will look for a column named `id`.

Comment: THATS IT!! problem solved!

Comment: I will add it as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments I believe the issue is that SQL Server uses case-sensitive column names by default (more specific information [can be found at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290124%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#dvmsccasesensitivity)), while Oracle will only use case-sensitive column names if these are enclosed in double quotes `"`. So if the column `id` in your SQL Server table is lowercase, you'll need to use quotes around this column name in Oracle. That is, if you don't put quotes around a column name in Oracle, it assumes uppercase. So `z.id` will look for a column named `ID` while `z."id"` will look for a column named `id`. Specifically, this line:

```
LEFT JOIN my_table@link z ON e.emp_id = z.id
```

should be this:

```
LEFT JOIN my_table@link z ON e.emp_id = z."id"
```

Hope this helps.